# Return a value from a Mono call

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, reactive-programming

Newbie to reactive programming in JAVA, I have a function `buildRow` that makes an async call to get hold of id and then use that determine a boolean value, this function always return's before async call gets completed. How do i make it return only after the async call completes and boolean value is determined?

```
public Row buildRow(Row row) {
    Mono<Long> id = reader.getColumn(row.getId());
    id
        .doOnNext(value-> {
            boolean isEnabled = reader.isEnabled(value);
            // This is getting returned second
            testRow(row, isEnabled);
         })
         .subscribe();
    // This is getting returned first
    return row;
}

public Row testRow(Row row, boolean isEnabled) {
  if (isEnabled) {
     return row;
  } else {
    return new Row();
  }
}

// Triggered in another function like this
map(row -> buildRow(row))
```

Comment: What is your reason for not returning a `Mono<Row>`?

Comment: All the upstream methods expect a `Row`, Is there a way to convert Mono<Row> to Row? All those methods seem to expect a synchronous flow whereas this is the only place an async call is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch your logic to that one:

```
public Mono<Row> buildRow(Row row) {
    return reader.getColumn(row.getId())
            .map(reader::isEnabled)
            .filter(isEnabled -> isEnabled)
            .map(enabled -> row)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(new Row()));
}
```

After that, you can change invocation of buildRow method from:

`map(row -> buildRow(row))`

to:

`flatMap(row -> buildRow(row))`

Otherwise, there is no sense in mixing reactive with a nonreactive approach in reader logic. The more you mix, the more problems you got.

Answer (score 0):

A `Mono` is a specialized `Publisher` that can contain only zero or one events.
In the `Mono<T>` Class, there is `block()` method:

```java
public T block()
```

> Subscribe to this Mono and block indefinitely until a next signal is received. Returns that value, or null if the Mono completes empty. In case the Mono errors, the original exception is thrown (wrapped in a RuntimeException if it was a checked exception).

In summary, `block()` method is used to get the `T` type value. Now, you could use `block()` method to return your `Row` Type value.

Code as followed:

```java
public Row buildRow(Row row) {
    Mono<Long> id = reader.getColumn(row.getId());
    Row row = id.map(value-> {
            boolean isEnabled = reader.isEnabled(value);
            // use map return value
            return testRow(row, isEnabled);
         })
         .block();  // use block to compute and then get value
    // Now what you want could return
    return row;
}
```